# Angularjs handling promises without $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I've got a factory that creates a SubCon $resource for a restful api.

```
app.factory("SubCon", function($resource) {
  return $resource("http://localhost:8010/api/subcontractors/:id");
})
```

I've got a controller that uses that service, and directly passes the promise returned by querying the service to an ng-repeat.

```
//in the controller
$scope.partners = this.SubCon.query();
```

Here is the repeat in the template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="partner in partners">
    <td>{{partner.id}}</td>
    <td>{{partner.name}}</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>---</td>
    <td>?</td>
</tr>
```

This works great and outputs what I expect.
So we have a policy against using $scope so I refactored the controller and template like this:

```
//in the controller
this.getPartners = function() { 
  return this.SubCon.query();
}
```

And the template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="partner in ctrl.getPartners()">
    <td>{{partner.id}}</td>
    <td>{{partner.name}}</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>---</td>
    <td>?</td>
</tr>
```

Now when I run this code using angular 1.5.8 I get a digest error as seen below.

So what am I missing. Why does this work with $scope and not using a method on the controller?

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:68
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17562)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17790)
    at done (angular.js:11831)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12033)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11966)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13920
angular.js:17793 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$scope.partners = this.SubCon.query();` by `this.partners = this.SubCon.query();`

Then you can pass a collection normally to ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="partner in ctrl.partners">
```